# Ошибка "The name 'Keyboard' does not exist in the current context" при проверке нажатия клавиши

Tags: unity3d, 2d

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(Keyboard.W)) transform.Translate(0, 1, 0);
    speedX = -horizontalSpeed;

}
```

Ошибка:

> The name 'Keyboard' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

Замените `Input.GetKey(Keyboard.W)` на `Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)`.

Comment: Спасибо, а почему он вверх не идет??

Comment: @IvanBrazhnik это уже другой вопрос (: